Последовательный вывод букв одна за другой
Как сделать так, чтобы слово не появилось сразу, а буква за буквой.
В коде ниже Hello World! появляется сразу и полностью.
Я пишу на cxxdroid, так как пк нет у меня и использую версию c++ 17.
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char textSleep[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','w','o','r','l','d','!'};
    int j = sizeof(textSleep)/sizeof(char);
    for(int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        cout << textSleep[i];
        Sleep(200);
    }
    return 0;
}


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Нуу так как в игре доки доки или чёт другое текст идёт букву за букву чтобы это было видно а не сразу за 0.004 секунд

https://stackoverflow.com/q/22026751/4711135

В cxxdroid, по-моему, можно устанавливать любые библиотеки — нет?


Функция Sleep() относится к библиотеке <windows.h>. А значит по понятнам причинам, на linux и онлайн - компиляторах работать не будет. Как вариант замены - библиотека <unistd.h>, и функция usleep()

Если мы хотим вывести в одну строку, то необходимо очищать буфер, тк иначе все выведется моментально. Для этого можно использовать, библиотеку <stdio.h> и функцию fflush(stdout)


Код программы:
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char textSleep[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','w','o','r','l','d','!'};
    int j = sizeof(textSleep)/sizeof(char);
    for(int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        cout << textSleep[i] << " ";
        usleep(20000);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}


Спасибо большое)

@HMEi пожалуйста

Ожидание можно сделать и средствами стандартной библиотеки.
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char textSleep[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','w','o','r','l','d','!'};
    int j = sizeof(textSleep)/sizeof(char);
    for(int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        std::cout << textSleep[i] << std::flush;
        //или std::cout.flush();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    }
    return 0;
}

